# Sitecore Package installation error

Tags: package, sitecore

When we select .zip file to install. following error occurring:

[image: picture of error]

Answer (score 1):

Possible you have this installed:
something based on [restrict-certain-types-of-files-from-being-uploaded-in-sitecore](http://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/10/04/restrict-certain-types-of-files-from-being-uploaded-in-sitecore/) or mabye this code [block-files-by-mime-content-type-from-being-uploaded-in-sitecore](http://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2013/11/block-files-by-mime-content-type-from-being-uploaded-in-sitecore.html) with exactly the same Error message in the code.

It is also possible that there is a other upload restriction process used, check the config section.

```
<sitecore><processors><uiUpload>
```

With `/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx`

Or you have the Upload restrictions from Sitecore.
See [secure_the_file_upload_functionality](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_hardening/configuring/secure_the_file_upload_functionality)
(but the error message is different must another version then the 1.0.0.2) For the Upload restrictions there is a [package](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Security%20Hardening%20Guide.aspx) Upload `Filter-1.0.0.2.zip`

If you have installed the Upload Restriction package you have a config file:

```
\App_Config\Include\UploadFilter.config
```

And there you can set .zip as not allowed. Remove the .zip from the Blocked extensions or try to put the package directly inside the package folder instead of uploading.

Comment: If the Upload Restrictions has been used, the error message would have been as follows: Uploading files with .zip extension is restricted

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Seems to be the exact message of the second link provided `"The file \"{0}\" cannot be uploaded. Files with an content Type of {1} are not allowed."`. Apart from which, there was nothing to stop the user editing the message themselves...

Comment: Yep likely from Yogesh the second link, I edit the answer a little bit with this.